# What Sort Method should be used?

Tags: arrays, sorting

Does the following problem have a sort or an algorithmic name that i can start to research on how to solve?

Given three 2d arrays `{x, y}` solve for the max sum of x, selecting 1 value from the first array, 2 values from the 2nd array, and 3 values from the third array, where the sum of y is under z value.

```
Array 1: [{3,1}, {4,2}, {6,3}, {7,4}, {10,5}, {12,6} ,{12,7}]
Array 2: [{1,2}, {3,5}, {5,5}, {5,6}, {8,3}, {13,6} ,{14,5}]
Array 3: [{1,1}, {1,3}, {2,1}, {2,2}, {2,3}, {2,5} ,{4,6}]
Z: 15
```

My current thoughts are to get all the arrays that fit under the criteria of z, and than sort the sum of the resulting arrays. This logic to me seems at best n^2.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: It looks like a variation on the [0-1 Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).  The usual approach to solving this family of problems efficiently is dynamic programming.

Comment: I'd suggest sorting Array1, Array2 and Array3 by the y value, and then follow @JohnBollinger suggestion of the knapsack problem.

Comment: thank you, that helps out a bunch